# How to make class searchable inside vector?

Tags: c++, class, search, vector

Say we have a C++ `class { std::string name; std::string surname /*..other members..*/};` we want it be searchable inside vector by that 2 strings (name, surname). How to do such thing? What members/operator overloads shall I implement? Or some hashing function?

Comment: For such searching operations by key, Use Map or Multimap.

Comment: You just need the correct Predicate and `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a vector, using `std::find`, you'll need `operator==`
(which should logically be accompanied by `operator!=`; it's
very bad practice to provide just one, even if the standard
library doesn't require it).  Or you could use `std::find_if`,
and explicitly provide the comparison.

If you want to sort the vector, and use `std::lower_bounds` on
it, or put the objects in `std::set` (or use them as a key to
`std::map`), you'll need `operator<` (which should imply the
operators `<=`, `>` and `>=` as well, to be coherent).  Again,
you can provide an explicit comparison instead.  `!(a < b) &&
!(b < a)` implies equality here, so if you're implementing all
six operators, you'll probably what that to also imply `a == b`.

For `std::unordered_set` (or as a key in `unordered_map`, you'll
need a hash function as well, which must be consistent with
`operator==`; i.e. if `a == b`, then `hash(a) == hash(b)`; the
reverse obviously can't hold, but there should be a high
likelyhood that it does for any two arbitrary `a` and `b`.

For example, in your case, to match by name and surname, you
might define:

```
class MatchName
{
    std::string targetName;
    std::string targetSurname;
public:
    MatchName( std::string const& targetName, std::string const& targetSurname )
        : targetName( targetName )
        , targetSurname( targetSurname )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( ClassType const& obj ) const
    {
        return obj.name == targetName
            && obj.surname == targetSurname;
    }
}
```

or if you want to keep the data sorted:

```
class OrderByName
{
public:
    bool operator()( ClassType const& lhs, ClassType const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
            || (lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.surname < rhs.surname);
    }
};
```

and for unordered containers:

```
template <typename T> struct Hash;
template<>
struct Hash<ClassType>
{
    bool operator()( ClassType const& obj ) const
    {
        return 127 * hash<std::string>( obj.name )
            + hash<std::string( obj.surname );
    }
};
```

(If you're using `operator==`, you will probably want to define
a specific instantiation of `std::hash`, so that the compiler
will pick it up by default; this is one of the rare times you
can, and indeed almost have to add something to namespace
`std`.)

Depending on the semantics of the class, it might make sense to
provide a set of these.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `std::vector`, the best approach is probably to use `std::find_if()`. That will let you define a custom predicate which will be applied to each element, searching for whatever you need. The predicate can be any callable type; if you're using C++11 then a lambda is ideal.

Here's an example of using an inline lambda (I'm assuming the `Name` class is as you've described in your question):

```
std::vector<Name> vec;
// populate the vector with names...

auto iter = std::find_if(
    vec.begin(),
    vec.end(),
    [](const Name &n) { return n.name == "Random" && n.surname == "Person"; }
);

if (iter != vec.end()) {
    // search was successful
}
```

You can also use stored lambdas or pre-defined functions/functors as the predicate.

Comment: Depending on the semantics of the class, it might make sense to pre-define several useful predicates (e.g. `MatchName`/`OrderByName`, `MatchSomethingElse`/`OrderBySomethingElse`).  Or to define `operator==` and `operator!=` (and maybe four operators for inequality as well).

Comment: The equality/inequality operators probably don't make sense in the context, since the class contains additional data which may be independent of the names.

Comment: Or may.  We don't know the full semantics of the class, so we cannot say.  (If the class is copiable, then the operators for `==` and `!=` likely do make sense.  Although perhaps not with the semantics he wants for his lookup.)